# CakePHP emails plugin - using a custom server

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, datasource, imap

I am trying to make a sort of email client.
I found the following CakePHP datasource class: https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-emails-plugin

It seems very good, however I have one question regarding the server details. In the plugin's readme it says that you should add the IMAP server as a an entry into your database.php config file.

My problem is that, since my website allows users to choose their own IMAP server, I can't hardcode a specfic server into the config file.

How would I redesign the code (or perhaps you can change database settings from the controller) to fit my purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not quite the same as when I first wrote it, but you can add database configs on the fly, see https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/app_model.php#L371

you also might want to look at the original code as it does exactly what you want to do, https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/tree/beta/core/emails

here is the actual code getting the emails of a particular users account https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/core/emails/controllers/mail_systems_controller.php#L25

it also has all the code for users to add their account details etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a datasource, I believe you could simply set the imap server on the fly.

```
$this->emailTicket['server'] = $servername;
```

Comment: i dont think thaw will work as the data is being set in the __construct() https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-emails-plugin/blob/master/models/datasources/imap_source.php#L146

Comment: Did you try?  I'm only asking because we use something similar to set the database name on the fly based on the subdomain name.

Comment: Well, that answers that, then :)